# Is there a need to unify variables with Unsigned type?

Tags: c#, c++, types, unsigned

For example, i don't need a negative number for any calculation, so i use uint. But, when floating point is needed, there is no Unsigned type and can't be maintained consistently. Or do you simply use Unsigned for bit patterns or more ranges?

Comment: Which programming language are you speaking about? Please tag.

Comment: C++ and C#. It is mainly C#.

Comment: What's the context in which you want only non-negative floating point numbers?

Comment: I'm making games, and floating point used for various purposes such as score and height measurement.

Comment: I use unsigned for bit storage only, signed for everything else. I've never needed the extra bit for range. In C++, unsigneds has an unfortunate semantics in certain cases. For example, subtracting from an unsigned int doesn't give you a signed type, so `for (unsigned int i=0; i<s-1; i++)` could for UINT_MAX, instead of skipping the loop.

Comment: Thanks! A good example. I will also use Unsigned only when it is needed specifically.